# change values of nested objects by id with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose

I'm new to MongoDB, and I'm trying to do a very simple task, but however I can't get it right.

What I want is to change the process status but I tried "FindAndUpdate", "UpdateOne" and "FindByIdAndUpdate" but it won't work.

Maybe it has to do with my Schema. Should I create a new Schema for the Process?

My Database entry inside a MongoDB Collection:

```
_id: 622c98cfc872bcb2578b97a5
username:"foo"
__v:0
 process:Array
  0: Object
   processname:"bar"
   process_status:"stopped"
   _id: 6230c1a401c66fc025d3cb88
```

My current Schema:

```
const User = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: { type: String, required: true },
        process: [
            {
                processname: {
                    type: String,
                },
                process_status: {
                    type: String,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    { collection: "user-data" }
);
```

My current code:

```
const startstopprocess = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
            { _id: "6230c1a401c66fc025d3cb88" },
            { process_status: "started" }
        ).then(function (error, result) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log(result);
        });
```

Comment: The user can add multiple processes.

Comment: J.F.'s answer is what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use positional operator [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) in this way:

```
db.collection.update({
  "process._id": "6230c1a401c66fc025d3cb88"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "process.$.process_status": "started"
  }
})
```

Note how using positional operator you can say mongo "from the object you have found in find stage, update the `process_status` variable to `started`"

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sAbusz9HJ-K)